# Check the chance of getting scholarship for phd program

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, allowed-questions

Dear stackexchange users!

I have a question and that might be weird to be asked in here. However if it's not the appropriate place to ask this question in this forum, please comment here and I will remove it. so the question is this:

> Is it a right place to post my concise version of CV here so that you can tell me what is my chance to get an scholarship for Phd program based on your academic experience?

Also If it is not the right forum please help me to find the right one.

P.S. I have B.SC and M.SC in electrical engineering major in power system and would like to apply for phd as international student.

Comment: I think that you can ask general questions about scholarships if you wish, but, because Academia is not a forum, you should not post your CV to ask for the chance to get a scholarship. You can ask general questions and might want to post some informations about yourself but not your whole CV.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the right place for such a question.

From the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> #### Can I ask questions about my specific situation?
>
> You should not ask "a question that will help only me," but rather "a question that will help people like me." If your question is so limited as to be useful only to you, consider broadening the scope so others can learn from your question as well. As a general rule, if you're asking about a particular institution, course, or journal, it's likely your question is too limited in scope. Try to extract the fundamental question from the specific problem at hand.

Comment: Yes, got it sir, so I will ask my question in general in here.@ff524

Comment: @Electricman One might consider not addressing people generally as "Sir", especially given ff524's avatar.

Comment: That's right, it was a misstake @Fomite